# Introducing: Jormungand

Tags: grid-deduction

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #32: Grid Deduction Hybrids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5998/2071)</sup>

---

Introducing: **Jormungand**

A combination of [Ouroboros (Slitherlink)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink) and [Numbersnake (Numbrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidato) to create the greatest snake-themed grid-logic puzzle the world has ever seen![Citation Needed]

- Each Numbered clue is a clue to the Ouroborus, as you may have guessed
- Each Numbered clue is also a portion of a clue to the Numbersnake: i.e. a 1 could represent a 1, or it could represent a 12, or a 31. Any number that contains that digit.
- All other rules of Ouroborus and Numbersnake apply.

[image: Triangles, Triangles Everywhere!]

Comment: Diagonals allowed?

Comment: Am I missing something?  The top-right two ones seem to indicate that a slitherlink is impossible.

Comment: So, is this on an icosahedron or something? (Also, how could it be a 31 if there are only 20 triangles?) And are the two puzzles entirely separate?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 yes, you are missing something. Deusovi he's just giving an example, but yes he should've chosen 11 or something instead.

Comment: @Deusovi 31 as an example doesn't apply to a puzzle of this size (but may apply to a potential future puzzle using similar rulesets), and the two puzzle solutions are separate save for their layout and clues.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 it appears that this is a 3D puzzle. Gonna nope outta here, have fun y'all!

Comment: I am gonna say like @greenturtle3141 this puzzle is either wrong, or it is a 3D puzzle even though it was not mentioned at all.... If it is a 3D puzzle, I am staying the hell away from this one XD

Comment: @stack Read the chat between the OP and Deusovi...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jormungand is (a variant of) the name for the snake in Norse mythology that wrapped around the earth. This is apparently (According to OP) a hint that

> This is a 3D puzzle!

Most people realised this when they discovered the image given is impossible to solve.

So the first step is realising the image given is a

> net of an icosahedron - a 3d shape with 20 faces.

I cut it out, folded it and stuck it together to get:

> [image] ta da!

---

**I also created (a pretty rubbish) 3d model - viewable [here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9AttmH8dXvm-fantabulous-allis/editv2?sharecode=C8LgUD3S5rJ40ozWk8WSiD-Nks5KkHcja0qGYmo1Hy8=)** (I believe the link may expire after a while, if it does and you want to see, ping me and I can update.)

---

Note: [I solved the slitherink](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=38284067#38284067) the day before greenturtle answered, but my mum made me go to bed because it was late so I didn't have time to write up an answer myself.

I solved the slitherink the same way as greenturtle did, [so go upvote his answer too](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52835/18250) and see it for the explanation. I will borrow his picture of the completed net because it is neater:

> [image]

Now the solution to the numbrix.

The first thing I thought of was that the two 0s must be 10 and 20. Both 0s are connected to a chain of empty triangles that lead up to a 2. These empty triangles must be the numbers 3-9.

> [image] [image]

So the question is which 0 is the 10? Well there are 7 numbers 3-9 and for only one of the 0s allows 7 spaces to the 2 (the one furthest left in the picture) and the other requires an extra 2 numbers. so we can fill out numbers 2-10 + 20:

> [image]

Now from 10 there is only one direction 11 12 can go so we can fill those in:

> [image]

From there 13-19 are pretty straightforward

> [image] (the 0 here should be a 20)

And we get the final number:

> [image]

Here is the final net:

> [image]

How it works:

> [image]

Great puzzle! Very enjoyable

Answer (score 18):

(Partial)

Like Deusovi pointed out, it appears that this is puzzle is probably the net of an icosahedron, and so this puzzle is actually in 3D.

Clearly the 3D is scary, and trying to solve it as-is will make both the solver and the reader bored. So...

> Yay! 
>  [image: prep]
>  [image: dun]

X'ing out the edges of the 0 triangle reveals some basic deductions:

> [image: firststep]

Now...

> [image: secondstep] 
>  We must X out this edge. If it was part of the Slitherlink, then the line will get trapped.

Also noteworthy:

> [image: thirdstep] 
>  This edge must be part of the Slitherlink. If it was not, then the other two edges of the 2 triangle must be part of the Slitherlink. You can see why this would be absurd.

Now look:

> [image: fourthstep] 
>  The line must go down, by process of elimination. It can't go left because one of the 1 triangles will have 2 filled edges, and it can't go up-right because the other 1 triangle will not be able to have any filled edges.

Next:

> [image: fifthstep] 
>  Going backward a bit, we see that we must connect these two parts together!

Finally, the rest of the Slitherlink is forced and does not warrant further discussion:

> [image: yey] 
>  
>  [image: dun]

Completed net:

> [image: DUNDUNDUN]

The Slitherlink is done! I don't know about the other part.

Comment: Someone actually went ahead and took the time to do it. Good job.

Comment: I just posted the solution for the Numbrix. Should we make a community wiki to join answers for a full solution?

Comment: Nicely solved, that's a far prettier folding job than I'd have managed